# POST request reverse Proxy

Tags: tomcat, reverse-proxy

First, sorry for my bad english because I'm french, but I've a problem with a reverse proxy.

I've a website with a Tomcat and I configured HTTPS on it and he is placed behind a reverse proxy to access on my website from outside of my LAN.
I have put a filter on my Tomcat to log all requests on my Tomcat. When I do POST requests outside my LAN, all parameters of my request are deleted of it, and the request fail. 
Is the problem related to my Tomcat or reverse proxy?

Here is the configuration of my server.xml

```
    <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="15360"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxPostSize="0" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
-->
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
     documentation -->


<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="15360"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="E:/.keystore" keystorePass="rootroot"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" server="commodore 64"/>


<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```